# time of data.table join

Tags: sql, r, join, data.table

I have two `data.table`s in R:

```
> tables()
     NAME          NROW   MB COLS                                 KEY       
[1,] dtb      2,536,206   68 dte,permno,capm_beta,mkt_beta_bucket permno,dte
[2,] idx_dtb        573    1 dte                                  dte       
[3,] ssd_dtb 58,808,208 1571 dte,permno,xs_ret,mkt_cap            permno,dte
Total: 1,640MB
```

I would like to do a right outer join: `select * from dtb right join ssd_dtb using (permno, dte)`

The equivalent command in `data.table` would be:

```
mdtb <- dtb[ssd_dtb]
```

So far this has been running for about 20 minutes.  This seems a bit long as it would normally take less time on an SQL server to run.  Am I misusing the package?

EDIT AFTER QUESTION ANSWERED:
I thought it might be helpful to understand why I had to do `dtb[ssd_dtb]` and not `ssd_dtb[dtb]`.  I devised a quick example:

```
> x <- data.table(id=1:5, t=1:15, v=1:15)
> x
    id  t  v
 1:  1  1  1
 2:  2  2  2
 3:  3  3  3
 4:  4  4  4
 5:  5  5  5
 6:  1  6  6
 7:  2  7  7
 8:  3  8  8
 9:  4  9  9
10:  5 10 10
11:  1 11 11
12:  2 12 12
13:  3 13 13
14:  4 14 14
15:  5 15 15
> y <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,3), t=c(1,2,6,13), v2=41:44)
> y
   id  t v2
1:  1  1 41
2:  1  2 42
3:  2  6 43
4:  3 13 44

> x[y]
   id  t  v v2
1:  1  1  1 41
2:  1  2 NA 42
3:  2  6 NA 43
4:  3 13 13 44
> x[y, nomatch=0]
   id  t  v v2
1:  1  1  1 41
2:  3 13 13 44
> y[x]
    id  t v2  v
 1:  1  1 41  1
 2:  1  6 NA  6
 3:  1 11 NA 11
 4:  2  2 NA  2
 5:  2  7 NA  7
 6:  2 12 NA 12
 7:  3  3 NA  3
 8:  3  8 NA  8
 9:  3 13 44 13
10:  4  4 NA  4
11:  4  9 NA  9
12:  4 14 NA 14
13:  5  5 NA  5
14:  5 10 NA 10
15:  5 15 NA 15
> y[x, nomatch=0]
   id  t v2  v
1:  1  1 41  1
2:  3 13 44 13
```

EDIT 2: The ouput of the above request for solution 1 is below:

```
> Rprof()
> mdtb  Rprof(NULL)
> summaryRprof()
$by.self
               self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"[.data.table"     15.36    62.39      24.62    100.00
".Call"             7.96    32.33       7.96     32.33
"pmin"              0.92     3.74       1.16      4.71
"list"              0.24     0.97       0.24      0.97
"vector"            0.14     0.57       0.14      0.57

$by.total
               total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"[.data.table"      24.62    100.00     15.36    62.39
"["                 24.62    100.00      0.00     0.00
".Call"              7.96     32.33      7.96    32.33
"pmin"               1.16      4.71      0.92     3.74
"list"               0.24      0.97      0.24     0.97
"vector"             0.14      0.57      0.14     0.57
"integer"            0.14      0.57      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 24.62
```

Comment: Are those two key field really set up as pks and thus indexed? You are returning alot of records I would never expect this to be fast but it will certainly be faster if you have proper indexing.

Comment: this is in R using the `data.table` package...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I can guess without a reproducible example, I'll try. In this case a few things do spring to mind. Good question.

1. There is one TODO in the source which could cause a large slowdown in this case. I wasn't aware it was as bad as that, though. If you know that `dtb`'s key is unique (i.e. no duplicated `dte` within each `permno`), as is very likely here, then set `mult="first"` to work around it. Or `mult="last"` would be the same. What it's doing is finding the start and end point of groups, but when a key is unique all those groups are just 1 row.
2. A smaller effect may be that the `i` table is large compared to `x` in your case. If possible, try to arrange the query with `i` smaller than `x`; i.e. `ssd_dtb[dtb]` rather than `dtb[ssd_dtb]`. They would be the same when `nomatch=0`.

If the workaround in 1 helps, it would be great if you could run the following and send me the results. Also, please raise a `bug.report(package="data.table")` linking back to this question. That way you'll get automatic updates as the status changes.

```
Rprof()
dtb[ssd_dtb]  # reduce size so that this takes 30 seconds or something manageable
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

Rprof()
dtb[ssd_dtb,mult="first"]  # should be faster than above if my guess is right
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
```

Comment: ok, very good let me give some of this stuff a try and i'll send the output. if that is the case in 1: maybe i can make a suggestion to incorporate an option for primary keys here so `[.data.table` could avoid this but still keep the functionality in the case that the key is not unique? thanks for your response as always.

Comment: Good idea. We have discussed unique keys on datatable-help before, but no feature request for it. Now raised : [FR#2214](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2214&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: Also correct me if I'm wrong but: ssd_dtb[dtb] is not the same as dtb[ssd_dtb].  I need this to be an outer join (that is `nomatch=0` would not work).  As far as I can tell, the two available joins in `data.table` in SQL language is inner join and right join.  Left join does not exist here so your second point wouldn't work? The reason I need an outer join is because i actually set `roll=TRUE`

Comment: WOW: I just ran solution 1 across my entire dataset. it finished in about 10 seconds. AMAZING!!!

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for sorting that out.

Comment: @Alex Good - 10 seconds for LOCF on 58m rows is more like it. Please raise the bug report then, so it's not forgotten to prevent the slow down somehow. You're right that `X[Y]` is not the same as `Y[X]`. I only wrote they would be when `nomatch=0`. So if you need outer join (`nomatch=NA`), then you're right that option 2 won't work in this case.

Comment: @MatthewDowle How does one raise a bug report? Sorry I'm a bit new to this stuff.

Comment: @Alex Type the bug report command I included in the answer ;)

Comment: yeh i looked that up but that opens up an email client apparently .. i dont have an email client installed... i'll give it a try and see what happens

Comment: @Alex That's odd, opens a webpage for me. Maybe `?bug.report` helps. If not just go to data.table homepage and click link to bugs & features.

Comment: yes, it's because i am working on a remote machine. it basically says to email you when i type that command in.

Comment: @Alex Ok. Then I wrote "if not ..." in previous comment. Are you able to do that, or shall I file it?

Comment: nope i got it. it wasn't working before and i realized later it was because i had to register. took care of it. thanks!